# Prove that problem is NP-complete: Given alphabet and regular expression check if this regular expression generates word with all symbols

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, np-complete

> Prove that problem is $NP$-complete: Given alphabet $A$ and regular
>   expression check if this regular expression generate word containing
>    all symbols in $A$.

Keep in mind that alphabet is not fixed.  I have no idea how to solve it.  The good thing it to prove $NP$-hard at begin I think. I would like to reduce CNF-SAT problem, however I can't start.

Comment: You might consider posting this on one of the StackExchange websites: Computer Science or Theoretical Computer Science.

Comment: A regular expression describes a language. Let w be a word containing all symbols in A. Asking whether the regular expression generates a word is equivalent to asking whether the word is in the language. Given a regular expression (or its equivalent DFA) does there exists  TM that takes as input the DFA and w and then decides if the DFA accepts w? If not, then the problem is not even decidable.

Comment: @user137481 could you be more precisely ?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of how a regular expression can be converted into a DFA that recognizes the language described by the regular expression?

Comment: Yes, it can be done in polynomial time.

Comment: My lecturer claims that it is NP-complete.

Comment: Let w be a word containing all symbols in A. Since we can convert the reg expr into a DFA, asking whether the reg expr generates w is the same as first converting the reg expr into a DFA and then running the DFA on all possible w (there are an infinite number of such words). But checking whether a DFA accepts a word is undecidable since this is the acceptance problem. Unless I have misinterpreted your question, this problem is undecidable so it is not in NP-Complete. Problems in NP-Complete are decidable. It's just that there are no known polynomial algorithms.

Comment: Can you be more precise with your question?  Do you need to determine whether the regular expression matches some word $W_a$ containing the symbol $a$ for each $a\in A$?  Or whether it matches a single word $W_A$ containing all the symbols in $A$?

Comment: @user137841, that's not correct.  The acceptance problem for a regular expression (does the regular expression match a particular word) is certainly decidable.

Comment: *it matches a single word $W_A$ containing all the symbols in $A$.* In other words, there exists such word (accepted by this regex) that contains all symbols from $A$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Yes, you're right. The acceptance problem for a regular expression is decidable. My mistake. My interpretation of the OP's question is that the regular expression has to match at least one word that contains all symbols from the alphabet A. This is where I got stuck since there are are possibly an infinite list of such words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP's idea is correct; $\sf{3\text{-}SAT}$ can be reduced to this problem.  Given a CNF with $m$ clauses $(A,B,C,D,\ldots)$ and $n$ variables ($x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$), where each clause contains three literals, we can construct a corresponding regular expression on an alphabet with $m$ symbols; the regex will accept a word with all $m$ symbols if and only if the CNF is satisfiable.  Specifically, the regex consists of $n$ blocks of the form $\sf{(a_i \;\vert \; b_i)}$, where $\sf{a_i}$ ($\sf{b_i}$) is a string of the symbols corresponding to exactly those clauses that contain $x_i$ ($\neg x_i$).  (If $\sf{a_i}$ is empty, replace this by $\sf{(b_i)?}$, and vice-versa.)  For example, if the CNF is
$$
(x_1\vee\neg x_2\vee \neg x_3)\wedge(x_4\vee x_1\vee x_2)\wedge(\neg x_4 \vee x_5 \vee \neg x_2),
$$
then the regular expression is
$$
\sf{(AB)?(B\;\vert\;AC)A?(B\;\vert\;C)C?}.
$$
Any assignment of truth variables corresponds to a path through the regular expression, making a binary choice for each variable (resp., each block); a *satisfying* assignment (word) is one that makes every clause true (includes every symbol).

Comment: Further, the problem is NP-complete because it is in NP. Given a regex and alphabet, one can prove this regex accepts a string using every character in the alphabet - just provide the string! It takes linear time to check that this string is accepted by the regex, and one can always provide a string that's only Poly(|regex|) (argument via the NFA methinks).